# Redondeo de decimal .5 arriba en 1 y .499 hacia bajo 0

Tags: c#, math

Necesito que me redondee el valor de un tipo de dato Decimal que si esta en el rango de xxx.5xx se redondee a 1 y si es menor que xxx.499 se aproxime a 0

el ejemplo que tengo es este:

```
public static void Main()
{
decimal num1 = 6.499M;
decimal num2 = 6.5M;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", 
        decimal.Round(num1), decimal.Round(num2)));
}
```

en el primero el resultado deberia ser

6 y el segundo 7

es como un celling indicando que 0.5 lo suba a 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posiblemente lo que estés buscando es cambiar el [estilo de redondeo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netframework-4.8). El siguiente código:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        decimal num1 = 6.499M;
        decimal num2 = 6.5M;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", 
            Math.Round(num1, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),
            Math.Round(num2, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)));
    }
}
```

Genera como salida:

> ```
> 6, 7
> ```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY6xasNAEERr6SsWVxKchW3igDEujMFVBCEpAgkpltMhL@huze4pwQh9uyKJNCGN25l5M2N1aVncMLRKoYbXm0bn96ltUBWehWtBD12aaMRIFr6YKiiRQqZRRuDjE1BqzadIUjlLHhsIrV/DAR6Lh92u3P81NrOxneUTB@XGFW9C0T1RcL@lxZnFY8wW3ao30K37hYExnpQYL8ULt6HKpgkDKwMlVVemEGd5Yo/feDsL@3cnnJv/2OYOLM/He33aD8MP)</kbd>.

---

Los posibles estilos de redondeo son:

- `AwayFromZero` cuando un número está a caballo entre otros dos, se redondea hacia el número más cercano que esté más alejado de cero.
- `ToEven` cuando un número está a caballo entre otros dos, se redondea al número par más cercano.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Y gracias por darme a conocer [tio](https://tio.run), parece interesante.

Comment: Un placer, tío.